# retrieving today's entry in sqlite-phonegap-jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to ensure that only one entry is entered into the db per day. so i want to extract today's entry n if there is a result to the query i want to set a flag, which will disallow any further entries. Whereas, if no entry has been made for the current day yet then flag remains unset n it will allow addition.
can anyone help me in querying today's entry.Is there a timestamp inbuilt with sqlite that can be used? i am also inserting a date into my table as follows:

```
function change()
{
var d=new Date();
var date=d.getDate();
var month=d.getMonth();
var year=d.getFullYear();
var ts = date+':'+month+':'+year;
alert(ts);
var userIP= document.getElementById("userInput").value; 
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
function populateDB(tx) {

     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS READ (time VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, data FLOAT NOT NULL)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO READ (time, data) VALUES ("'+ts+'", "'+userIP+'")');
}
     function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
    db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
}
}
```

The above function is called when the user submits an entry and I want to enter the validation for single entry per day within the same function.

NOTE: all the alerts are for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As you have used "time" as the primary key so you can restrict the insert in two ways

1. Using ignore

   ```
   tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO READ (time, data) VALUES ("'+ts+'", "'+userIP+'")');
   ```
2. First retrieve, check and then insert

   ```
   tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM READ WHERE time = ?", [ts],
       function(tx, iResults) {
          if(iResults.rows.length <= 0) {
               db.transaction(function(tx) {
                   tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO READ (time, data) VALUES ("'+ts+'", "'+userIP+'")',[],
                       function() {
                           console.log("Inserted");
                       },
                       function() {
                           console.log("Not Inserted");
                       }
                    );
               });
           }
       },
       function() {
           console.log("Not Inserted");
       }
   );
   ```

Comment: With respect to the first soln you've offered, the time format that I'm entering into the Db is defined by me as seen in the beginning of the code.. will that matter? My doubt is, this soln will work for one day, then next day when the user tries to enter what happens? How does the ignore work then?

Comment: As you are entering time in this format dd:mm:yyyy, so lets say, for today 07:08:2013 is already entered, then if again the insert query is fired then it just don't insert the record, will ignore that record. Same happens with all records with time 07:08:2013, but on next day, the record will have time 08:08:2013, so in this case it will get inserted on the db.